# Applying post title filter: Last Viewed Posts + qTranslate

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I'm using Last Viewed Posts (LVP) plugin on a qTranslate-enabled website. LVP shows post titles in both languages. I found this hint: [titles in recent posts appear together in all languages with qtranslate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48322/titles-in-recent-posts-appear-together-in-all-languages-with-qtranslate)

But not sure how to apply this filter. Relevant code in LVP:

```
        foreach ($zg_post_IDs as $value) { // Do output as long there are posts
        global $wpdb;
        $zg_get_title = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '$value+0' LIMIT 1");
        foreach($zg_get_title as $zg_title_out) {
            echo "<a href=\"". get_permalink($value+0) . "\" title=\"". $zg_title_out->post_title . "\">". $zg_title_out->post_title . "</a>, \n"; // Output link and title
        }
```

Instead of `echo $post->post_title;` it has `$zg_title_out->post_title`.

Replacing the whole zg string with `apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title)` didn't work.

Comment: With some trial and error, solved (above).

Now I see that there's a semicolon after every post link. How can I omit the semicolon after the last link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution -**

take out:
`foreach($zg_get_title as $zg_title_out) {
            echo "<a href=\"". get_permalink($value+0) . "\" title=\"". $zg_title_out->post_title . "\">". $zg_title_out->post_title . "</a>, \n"; // Output link and title`

insert:

`foreach($zg_get_title as $post) { echo "<a href=\"". get_permalink($value+0) . "\" title=\"". $post->post_title . "\">". apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title) . "</a>; \n"; // Output link and title`

`$zg_title_out` was replaced with `$post`,
and `$zg_title_out->post_title` was replaced with `$post->post_title`